# Pages are a random mess

Tags: php, pagination

The page function on my blog isn't pulling its weight.  When page two is clicked, it skips ahead to page three.  When  page one is clicked, page two loads. I found this function on the web somewhere; it is not my own.

```
function generate_pages($total,$current)
{
    if($total > 1)
    {
        $total=intval($total);

        $output='<div class="page"><b>Pages:</b>  ';
        $current_page= (false == isset($current)) ? 1 : $current;
        for($page=1;$page<$total+1;$page++)
        {
            $lower=$current_page-3;
            $upper=$current_page+3;
            $special = ($page==$current_page) ? " class=\"current\"" : "";
            if(($page > $lower && $page < $upper) || $page < 2 || $page > ($total-1))
            {
                if($last_done_page+1 != $page) $output.= '... ';
                $output.='<b>[<a'.$special.' href="?pg='.$page.'">'.$page.'</a>] </b>';
                $last_done_page=$page;
            }
        }
        $output.='</div><br/>';
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that WAS indeed terrible...

Comment: How did you try to fix it, did you debug it? Why don't you write a better function instead of relying on random crap from the internets?

Comment: The code is from this question: [How can I improve this PHP pagination algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744794/how-can-i-improve-this-php-pagination-algorithm)

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I don't understand the question, either. http://codepad.org/Py1YoVrm the code works as it should. Clicking on 1 will take you to `?pg=1` If that's not what you want... then... what? Maybe your pages are 0-based so clicking 1 (`pg=1`) means 2nd page somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Don't want to defer you from your current goal, but something to think about:  I usually use the browser's own paging mechanism.  If the content is larger than what will fit in the browser, a familiar to users paging control(scrollbar) is on the right, which clicking in the empty areas jumps entire pages.  The request is more efficient for data the consists of only a few pages, because it is provided in a single request, and doesn't require any server side chunking/filtering of the content.  Content spanning many pages is difficult for the user to find what they need, thus provide filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I think these changes will help you:

```
function generate_pages($total,$current,$resultsPerPage)
{
    if($total > 1)
    {
        $total=intval($total/$resultsPerPage);

    if($total%$resultsPerPage>0)
    {
        $total=$total+1;
    }



        $output='<div class="page"><b>Pages:</b>  ';
        $current_page= (false == isset($current)) ? 1 : $current;
        for($page=1;$page<$total+1;$page++)
        {
            $lower=$current_page-3;
            $upper=$current_page+3;
            $special = ($page==$current_page) ? " class=\"current\"" : "";
            if(($page > $lower && $page < $upper) || $page < 2 || $page > ($total-1))
            {
                if($last_done_page+1 != $page) $output.= '... ';
                $output.='<b>[<a'.$special.' href="?pg='.$page.'">'.$page.'</a>] </b>';
                $last_done_page=$resultsPerPage;
            }
        }
        $output.='</div><br/>';
        return $output;
    }
}
```

I have added one extra parameter  $resultsperPage.......